# Can an apostrophe be a part of a grapheme that represents a sound?

Tags: apostrophe

I've noticed that apostrophes aren't usually part of a grapheme that represents a particular sound.

Some examples: I'll, I'd, I've, Hugh's, Pat's, he's, I'm, you're, they're, we're, weren't, won't.  In each case, the apostrophe can be safely ignored.

But in some cases, apostrophes do appear to be part of a grapheme that represents a sound:

- <'s> as in Butch's - The <'s> here appears to represent an additional syllable made up of the phonemes /ɪz/.  Since  often represents a /z/ sound, the apostrophe here appears to represents the phoneme /ɪ/.
- <'> as in Jones' or James'.  Here the <'> appears to represent the  phonemes /ɪz/.
- <it'd>.  The word "it'd" can be pronounced /ɪtɪd/, /ɪtəd/ or /ɪd/.  So the apostrophe appears to at times represent the phoneme /ɪ/ or /ə/.
- <n'> as in isn't, doesn't, couldn't - Here the <n'> grapheme appears to represent the phonemes /ən/.

Given the above, the apostrophe at times appears to represent the phonemes /ɪ/, /ə/ or /ɪz/.  It's also part of a <n'> grapheme which represents the phonemes /ən/.

Are there other cases where the apostrophe can be a part of a grapheme that represents a sound?

Comment: **Apostrophes *never* make sounds.** Neither do letters. This question is not well constructed because it is asking for an answer to something that is not actually happening in the first place. Epenthetic insertion is all you're talking about here, and that is entirely different. It has to do with English phonology and the rules of  English phonotactics. It has nothing whatsoever to do with writing, only with speaking. Anyone is welcome to amplify the ***frame challenge*** inherent in this comment to use to compose a proper answer of their own.

Comment: @tchrist Would you not say, though, that letters and punctuation can _represent_ or _indicate_ sounds?

Comment: @tchrist - Apologies for my ignorance.  I was under the impression that graphemes are a letter (or group of letters) that represent a sound.  In this case, it appeared to me that an apostrophe was acting in a similar manner.

I will attempt to edit the question to adjust your feedback.

Comment: The apostrophe is often used to represent a consonant ('okina) in words from the Hawai'ian  Language. It is the only non-Latin grapheme allowed USGS official place names. Some fonts support a special glyph. The consonant is a glottal stop. [Hawai'ian Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_alphabet)

Comment: Forward and backward apostrophes are also used in [transliterating/romanizing Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic), amongst other languages. Some of these words have made it into English, such as [za'atar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/za'atar) زَعْتَر. These aren't usually pronounced with the Arabic consonant ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/za'atar) has /ˈzɑˌtɑr/), although MW says you can pronounce it in 3 syllables with some kind of syllable break for the apostrophe. So it's marginal at best.

Comment: @BoldBen: No, there are exceptions to all rules relating English spelling to English phonetics. And even more to rules going the other way -- that's why English but no other language distinguishes Spelling from Writing. Spelling English is a learned skill, like driving or drawing, and most English speakers don't get very good at it.

Comment: @JohnLawler I appreciate that, John. I know that there isn't a one to one correlation between letters or graphemes and sounds, one only has to think of the name of the English town Loughborough (pronounced Luffburruh) to know that. I was responding to the remark by tchrist that letters and graphemes don't _make_ sounds by suggesting a better way for the OP to present his question.

Answer (score 4):

In English, especially, it's often not obvious which groupings of letters constitute "graphemes", or how they correlate to sounds. (English spelling and pronunciation have a relationship that is ***not 100%*** arbitrary, but there are many areas where the relationship is partly arbitrary, complex, or underspecified.)

There is a blog post from the prominent linguist Geoffrey K. Pullum that addressed your question, and states that "It's by no means a trivial puzzle": "[Does the apostrophe ever represent a sound?](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3706)", *Language Log,*
January 16, 2012.